# Limit insertion of records into table in phpmyadmin wamp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm using WAMP. And below is the code of trigger to limit the record insertion in table. It gives error as #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER abc.

Please help me.

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER abc
BEFORE INSERT
  ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_row_cnt TINYINT(3);
BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_row_cnt FROM login_db;

  IF v_row_cnt > 10 THEN
     DELETE FROM my_table ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1;
  END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As error message states error is where the word `trigger` exist in your code and it is next to the words `create or replace`.

So Instead of `replace` you need `DROP` in mysql like `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS abc`. Yes must have to use `DELIMITER` see following two examples

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS abc;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER abc
BEGIN    
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login_db) > 10 THEN //method 3
        DELETE FROM my_table ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1;
     END IF;
END |
DELIMITER;
```

or

```
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS abc//    
CREATE TRIGGER abc
BEGIN
     set @somvar = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM login_db);
     IF @somvar > 10 THEN         
        DELETE FROM my_table ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1;
     END IF;
END //
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: After executing above 2nd one code giving error as : ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11